# Domain driven design: Handling atomic operations and transactions

Tags: transactions, domain-driven-design, atomic

Inside every aggregate the consistence must be guaranteed. It is easy to do it in the repository because I can always use transactions from the database or framework. I have doubts about what happens outside the repository. A service might need to work with more than one aggregate to process a request. There could be problems during the processing in the service or while the aggregates are persisted.

If something goes wrong during the processing in the service I could raise an exception. That way the operation will be atomic. This is my first concern. Is that a good practice? The problem I see is that it will be hard to recover from that. There will be no easy way to leave all the aggregates with the state they had before the failed operation.

The other problem I have is what happens if one of the aggregates fails to be persisted. How do I ensure the consistency of the information? Do I have to use database transactions outside the repositories? I was thinking that it might not be the best solution because I should not be thinking in the database when I am designing the domain model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is provided in the Unit of Work pattern - http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html

You can encapsulate as many aggregate root operations into a single UOW as you want. The unit of work concrete implementation can then contain its own commit and rollback logic, specific to the persistence method and technologies involved. For example, you deal with the `TransactionScope` object ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) if you were working in .NET.

Here is a decent article on how to implement a basic UOW pattern - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx

Comment: uow may solve this when everything is on one machine, but if aggregates can be distributed, people say distributed transactions is evil thing, and I wonder how uow helps in this case

Comment: Distributed Transactions is not a concern of UOW, or of anything on the domain. But, in .NET, TransactionScope handles distributed transactions, as I mentioned.

Comment: I thought there could be an easier approach. In the blue book everything looks simple and perfect, but in practice it is complicated. I find almost impossible to implement a decent domain design without the use of different frameworks and implementing stuff and layers everywhere to glue the entities in something that is “clearer and simpler” than an anemic-domain model.

Comment: @Pleonc - this is very true. Sometimes though, it is perfectly fine to just break one or two DDD "best practices" for the sake of avoiding some overly complicated and verbose implementation. After all, we are dealing with real business problems, real system integration challenges and real deadlines. The books are written on theory and best case scenarios.